# Add an attribute to the first link from a set of links using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, gallery

I need to add an attribute to the first link of a list of links in a project I'm working on and thinking of a way to do this using JavaScript. Here are the codes below, they are dynamically generated but what I want is to figure out a way to insert id="cover_title" in the first  tag of every list of with the sequence of , So that the code looks exactly like below. Any ideas?

```
<ul id="gallery">

<li id="album">
<div id="album_title">Summer 2012</div>
        <div id="photo"><a id="cover_title" href="#"><img src="images/photo1.png"/></a></div>
        <div id="photo"><a href="#"><img src="images/photo2.png"/></a></div>
        <div id="photo"><a href="#"><img src="images/photo3.png"/></a></div>
        <div id="photo"><a href="#"><img src="images/photo4.png"/></a></div>
        <div id="photo"><a href="#"><img src="images/photo5.png"/></a></div>

</li>

<li id="album">
<div id="album_title">Spring 2012</div>
        <div id="photo"><a id="cover_title" href="#"><img src="images/photo1.png"/></a></div>
        <div id="photo"><a href="#"><img src="images/photo2.png"/></a></div>
        <div id="photo"><a href="#"><img src="images/photo3.png"/></a></div>
        <div id="photo"><a href="#"><img src="images/photo4.png"/></a></div>
        <div id="photo"><a href="#"><img src="images/photo5.png"/></a></div>

</li>
```

Comment: ID should be unique across a document(page) and should not be duplicated.

Comment: Please use `photo1`, `photo2`,..,and so on instead of same `photo` everywhere and update your question accordingly...

Comment: the ID is unique, except would like to add id="cover_title" to the first <a> tag in each list.

Answer (score 2):

In the first place a note: `id` comes from identifier and has to be *unique* throughout the document. Your code should use the `class=""` attribute instead. See, e.g., [MDN on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.id):

> The ID must be unique in a document, ....

That being said, the below code sets the appropriate `class` on th `<a>`-element, assuming that you transformed all `id` attributes above into `class`.

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll( 'div.photo:nth-child(2) a' );
for( var i=0; i<links.length; ++i ) {
  links[i].classList.add( 'cover_title' );
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is an example fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/GFm8S/).

Answer (score 0):

Vega said it right: don't do dublicate ID, use class. Simple in jQuery

```
$('.album_title').each(function(){
  $(this).find('a:first').addClass('cover_title');
});
```